# Using the Slater determinant to find the associated antisymmetric wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, many-body, pauli-exclusion-principle

My lecture notes read:

[image]

If there is one electron in the ground state, one in the first excited state, and one in the second excited state, why can we not instantly assume then, that:

$$\phi_{n_i}(x_j) = 0, n \ne j$$

As in, why are all the off-diagonals not instantly $0$? If the ground energy eigenstate has just particle $1$ at position $x_1$, why can't we automatically assume, for instance, that $\phi_{n1}(x_2) = 0$ since the second particle is in the *first* energy eigenstate, not the ground state, so it's position $x_2$ cannot be found in the ground state?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the particles are indistinguishable. You can say that there is **one** particle in the ground state. You can't say that **particle $1$** is in the ground state.

To account for this indistinguishability, you wavefunction must be properly (anti-) symmetrized. In the case of two particles this is done by writing

$$\psi\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\phi_{1}\left(x_{1}\right)\phi_{2}\left(x_{2}\right)\pm\phi_{1}\left(x_{2}\right)\phi_{2}\left(x_{1}\right)\right)$$

Here $\phi_{n}$ is the wavefunction of state $n$ and $x_{i}$ is the index of the particle $i$. Note that nothing connects $i$ and $n$; the fact that I used numbers for both is just notation. The function $\phi_{n}$ doesn't know what index its argument has. It is just the single particle wavefunction of state $n$.

In your case you're given that, for instance, one of the three electrons sits in the ground state - but which one? All of them! And you must sum all the options in an anti-symmetric manner.

Answer (score 0):

The physics of $3$-particle systems is much more fun than the $2$-body case.

The initial thing to note is there is no such thing as “the first electron” or “the second electron”.  We need to give them numbers for discussion purposes but we make sure the labelling doesn’t matter in the probability density $\vert \Psi(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\vert^2$ by arranging the states so the total probability density doesn’t change when we permute any two labels.

The next thing to note is that, since your spin state is by the statement of your problem symmetric under permutation of particle labels, the spatial part must be antisymmetric since fermionic states must be overall antisymmetric under permutation of particle labels.  Thus the spatial part will be a determinant and requires at least $3$ *distinct* spatial functions else the determinant would be $0$ since two or more of the rows of columns would be the same,

Now for the (less discussed but) fun part.

It is possible for $3$ particles to have spins states of mixed symmetry.  The total spin $S=1/2$ states are of this type.  You can verify, for instance, that
$$
\vert\Psi_{(12)3;1/2,+}\rangle=\left[ \vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2 - \vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\right]\vert +\rangle_3 \tag{1}
$$
is in fact a $S=1/2, M=1/2$ state but it does not transform to a multiple of itself under permutation of - say - labels $1$ and $3$.  This isn’t a really big deal because you can take the state in (1), and the state $\vert\Psi_{1(23);1/2,+}\rangle$, and combine these two with 2 *spatial* wave functions, and obtain something either fully symmetric or fully antisymmetric.  In other words, $3$-particle spin states or spatial wavefunctions need not separately come back to themselves under permutations; it is the total spin+spatial states that must have this symmetry.

Finally, it is not possible to make a fully antisymmetric state from 3 spin-1/2 states, since each electron only has two distinct spin states.  As a result, it is not possible to have a fully symmetric spatial part to the total wavefunction of the system.